# I have a list of data frames and a character vector. I want to rename the second column of each data frame by iterating through the vector. How do I?

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes. Each of these dataframes has the same number of columns and rows, and has a similar data structure:

```
df.list <- list(data.frame1, data.frame2, data.frame3)
```

I have a vector of characters:

```
charvec <- c("a","b","c")
```

I want to replace the column name of the **second** column in each data frame by iterating through the above character vector. For example, the first data frame's second column should be "a". The second data frame's second column should be "b".

```
[[1]]
  col1 a
1    1    2
2    2    3

[[2]]
  col1 b
1    1    2
2    2    3
```

Comment: [@taistil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20222361/taistil) welcome to StackOverflow! Could you describe what you've tried and what didn't work? It seems that simply iterating `for (i in seq_along(df.list))` and assigning`colnames(df.list[i])[2] <- charvec[i]` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A *reproducible* example:

```
charvec <- c("a","b","c")
df_list <- list(df1 = data.frame(x = seq_len(3), y = seq_len(3)), df2 = data.frame(x = seq_len(4), y = seq_len(4)), df3 = data.frame(x = seq_len(5), y = seq_len(5)))

for(i in seq_along(df_list)){
  names(df_list[[i]])[2] <- charvec[i]
}
```

---

```
> df_list
$df1
  x a
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

$df2
  x b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4

$df3
  x c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can use `map2` from `purrr`. Thanks to @ismirsehregal for example data.

```
library(purrr)

map2(
  df_list,
  charvec,
  \(x, y) {
    names(x)[2] <- y
    x
  }
)
```

**Output**

```
$df1
  x a
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

$df2
  x b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4

$df3
  x c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```